# Google Cloud Storage Minimum Storage Capacity Per Object

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I know there is a minimum storage capacity (40KB) required for AWS Glaciers but after reading so many pages of GCP's documents, I can't find any mentioning of minimum storage capacity required for Google Cloud Storage. I don't know if I have missed it. Does anyone know if there is a requirement for minimum storage capacity on GCP? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) describes that there is **no** minimum object size in Google Cloud Storage:

> The following aspects apply to all storage classes:
>
> - Unlimited storage with **no minimum object size**.
> - Worldwide accessibility and worldwide storage locations.
> - Low latency (time to first byte typically tens of milliseconds).
> - High durability (99.999999999% annual durability).
> - Geo-redundancy if the data is stored in a multi-region or dual-region.
> - A uniform experience with Cloud Storage features, security, tools, and APIs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation:

> This page describes quotas and request limits for Cloud Storage

[Quotas & limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas)

> There is a maximum size limit of 5 TB for individual objects stored in
> Cloud Storage

However, the document does not mention anything about a minimum object size.

Therefore I believe GCS does not have this limit.